# Bootstrap/CSS div placement issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a little trouble placing a few divs inside a .well of a Twitter Bootstrap scaffolding page.  I have been working on it for a bit now, but my CSS knowledge is limited, I've mostly just taught myself.

http://jsfiddle.net/hEvwR/

It is supposed to look like this:

[image: The mock up]

This is originally in Jade, but I converted it for the question.  I'd love any suggestions for best practices on this page as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/hEvwR/2/

Change

```
    <div class="span5">
      <p><strong>Enter Your Mobile Phone Number</strong>
      </p>
      <input id="features-demo-number" type="text" placeholder="555-123-4567" style="text-align:center;padding:10px 12px;font-size:16px;margin-top:10px;" class="input-medium"/>
      <div class="pull-left">
        <p><strong>(Optional) Enter a MLS identification number for a more personalized demo</strong>
        </p>
        <input id="features-demo-mls-number" type="text" placeholder="123456789" style="text-align:center;padding:10px 12px;font-size:16px;margin-top:10px;" class="input-medium"/><br/>
        <button id="features-demo-customer" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Send <strong>Buyer</strong> Notification <i class="icon-share-alt icon-white"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <video id="video-preview" controls="controls" preload="auto" poster="images/poster.png" width="250" height="140" data-setup="{}" class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
          <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/textoad.com/assets/textoad.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </source>
        </video><a href="/signup" style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:0px;font-size:18px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;text-align:center;" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Sign Up Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

to

```
    <div class="span5">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <p><strong>Enter Your Mobile Phone Number</strong></p>
        <input id="features-demo-number" type="text" placeholder="555-123-4567" style="text-align:center;padding:10px 12px;font-size:16px;margin-top:10px;" class="input-medium"/>
        <p><strong>(Optional) Enter a MLS identification number for a more personalized demo</strong>
        </p>
        <input id="features-demo-mls-number" type="text" placeholder="123456789" style="text-align:center;padding:10px 12px;font-size:16px;margin-top:10px;" class="input-medium"/><br/>
        <button id="features-demo-customer" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Send <strong>Buyer</strong> Notification <i class="icon-share-alt icon-white"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <video id="video-preview" controls="controls" preload="auto" poster="images/poster.png" height="140" data-setup="{}" class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
          <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/textoad.com/assets/textoad.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </source>
        </video><a href="/signup" style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:0px;font-size:18px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;text-align:center;" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Sign Up Now</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And add

```
.span5{width:auto;}
#video-preview{width:210px!important;}
.span5>.pull-left{width:210px}
```

Comment: Cool, it's starting to fit.  I wasn't aware of the '!important' command, and that seems to do the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: @Alex Just for educational purposes: `!important` is a rule really, rather then command: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception